# Copy Canvas Image into a Frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

As starting point I have a image on my canvas:

```
var canvas = $('canvas')[0];
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var img=document.getElementById("scream");
   ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,240,297);
```

Now I would like to add a frame to this Image on the same canvas. For this:

**I first replace the image** with the Frame.

Next I try to copy the **old canvas content inside of this frame**

I try to do this like that:

```
   var frame = document.getElementById("frame");

   var ctx = $('canvas')[0].getContext("2d");
   var dst = ctx.canvas;

      ctx.drawImage(frame,0,0, 240, 297);
      ctx.drawImage(dst, 40, 40);
```

But the **code is not working** because it **copies the frame again** to the canvas instead of the image: Here you can see a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/35mxfsv0/

**What do I wrong? What do I have to change? Thanks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you just assign the original `canvas` to `dst`, when you draw anything on that canvas, the `dst` will also changed (because they're pointing to same canvas).

So you have to assign a new canvas to `dst`, and draw the image from `origin` to `dst`, then draw the frame on `origin`, and last, draw dst's image to origin.

```js
window.onload = function() { // Make it safe that window.onload ensures all images loaded.
  
  var canvas = $('canvas')[0];

  var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
  var img=document.getElementById("scream");

  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,240,297);

  //START OF MY CODE
  var frame = document.getElementById("frame");

  // Comment out as we demo in same scope, ctx is already have what we want.
  //var ctx = $('canvas')[0].getContext("2d");
  // Create a new canvas, and draw the image on the origin canvas to it.
  var dst = document.createElement('canvas');
  dst.width = canvas.width;
  dst.height = canvas.height;
  var dstCtx = dst.getContext('2d');
  dstCtx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
  // Above is what you suppose the canvas should do.
  //var dst = ctx.canvas;        

  // Draw frame
  ctx.drawImage(frame,0,0, 240, 297);

  // As your frame is not an opacity one, you have to copy to specific position.
  ctx.drawImage(dst, 0, 0, dst.width, dst.height, 10, 10, 220, 277);
}
```

```css
img{display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="240" height="297" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
</canvas>
    
    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_the_scream.jpg" id="scream"/>
    <img src="http://www.wpclipart.com/page_frames/picture_frames/wood_picture_frame.jpg" id="frame"/>
```

However, if you still have the access to that scream image, you can just draw frame first, then draw image on it:

```
var canvas = $('canvas')[0];

var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var img=document.getElementById("scream");
var frame = document.getElementById("frame");

ctx.drawImage(frame,0,0, 240, 297);
// 10, 10 seems to fit the frame.
ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change id of your html and js file.

Comment: describe your answer some more